# FloatingPanelController stops displaying content after upgrading from Floating Panel v1.7.5 to latest

Tags: ios, swift, xcode15

The "content" I am referring to is part of the contentViewController passed to fpc.set.  Using the old version, the content appears as expected, but after upgrading, the content vanishes. If I comment out the below code using the old version of Floating Panel, the content also disappears.

Does anyone see something in this code that should have also been changed when upgrading the Floating Panel version?  This pod was upgraded after moving to latest Mac OS, XCode, and our test iPad because it didn't otherwise work correctly.

```
        if let punchTVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PunchTableViewController") as? PunchTableViewController {
            punchTVC.dataSource = self
            fpc.set(contentViewController: punchTVC)
            fpc.track(scrollView: punchTVC.tableView)
            _punchTableView = punchTVC
            _punchTableView?.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
            _punchTableView?.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
        }
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.